# Algorithm to find all permutations of a given N with condition

Tags: java, c, algorithm, permutation

I am designing a program to print all permutations of a given N such that the each digit should be greater than the next digit.

For Example 
if N=3:
output should be 123,456,789,134,145,178,189 etc...

Initial Design:

1. Generate all possible permutations
2. Pass the generated permutation to a digit extraction function which checks for the condition
3. Print out the result

This is a very naive algorithm. But I do not know the implementation/initial design because of the dynamic size of N.

Comment: Is what you want the set of all N-digit decimal numbers for which the digits are distinct and increasing?

Comment: @TedHopp Yes..N is the given input to the function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since N will always be  less than 10, i've used recursion

Call the function as `f(3,0,0)`

```
public static void f(int N,int digit,int num)
    {
        if(N > 0 )
        {
            for(int d = digit + 1; d < 11 - N; d++) // earlier d < 10, see comments
            {
                f(N-1,d,num * 10 + d);
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println(num); //add it to a list or whatever
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
123
124
...
678
679
689
789
```

Comment: +1 Nicely done. A lot of useless work (particularly for large N) can be avoided by replacing `d < 10` in the `for` loop with `d < 11 - N`.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to do this is with recursion. Suppose you've generated the first *n* digits and the last digit generated is *i*. You have *N* - *n* digits left to generate and they must start with *i* + 1 or higher. Since the last digit can be no more than 9, the next digit can be no more than 10 - (*N* - *n*). This gives the basic rule for recursion. Something like this (in Java) should work:

```
void generate(int N) {
    int[] generated = new int[N];
    generate(generated, 0);
}

void generate(int[] generated, int nGenerated) {
    if (nGenerated == generated.length) {
        // print the generated digits
        for (int g : generated) {
            System.out.print(g);
        }
        System.out.println();
        return;
    }
    int max = 10 - (generated.length - nGenerated);
    int min = nGenerated == 0 ? 1 : (generated[nGenerated - 1] + 1);
    for (int i = min; i <= max; ++i) {
        generated[nGenerated] = i;
        generate(generated, nGenerated + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just generate them in lexicographic order:

```
123
124
125
...
134
135
...
145
...
234
235
...
245
...
345
```

This assumes you have digits at most 5. For larger bound `B`, just keep going. Some simple code to do this is:

```
nextW = w;
for (int i=n-1; i>=0; --i) {
    // THE LARGEST THE iTH DIGIT CAN BE IS B-(n-i-1)
    // OTHERWISE YOU CANNOT KEEP INCREASING AFTERWARDS
    // WITHOUT USING A NUMBER LARGER THAN B
    if w[i]<B-(n-i-1) {
        // INCREMENT THE RIGHTMOST POSITION YOU CAN
        nextW[i] = w[i]+1;
        // MAKE THE SEQUENCE FROM THERE INCREASE BY 1
        for (int j=i+1; j<N; ++j) {
            nextW[j] = w[i]+j-i+1;
        }
        // VOILA
        return nextW;
    }
}
return NULL;
```

Start with `w = [1,2,3,...,N];` (easy to make with a `for` loop), print `w`, call the function above with `w` as an input, print that, and continue. With `N = 3` and `B = 5`, the answer will be the above list (without the ... lines).

If there is no bound `B`, then you're SOL because there are infinitely many.

In general, you are computing the `N`th [elementary symmetric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) `e_N`.

Comment: @thinkcool See above. If it's unclear, please let me know which part is troublesome.

Comment: nextW = w; what does w contain initially?

Comment: Start with `w = [1,2,3,...,N]`, then generate the next one in lexicographic order with the function described above, which takes `w` as an input.

Comment: I think we do not need B, since we need to just print all the three digit numbers..

Comment: @thinkcool There are infinitely many without `B`. For example, 1 2 3, 1 2 4, 1 2 5, 1 2 6, 1 2 7, 1 2 8, 1 2 9, 1 2 10, 1 2 11, 1 2 12, 1 2 13, 1 2 14, 1 2 15, 1 2 16, 1 2 17, 1 2 18, 1 2 19, 1 2 20, 1 2 21, 1 2 22, 1 2 23, 1 2 24, 1 2 25, 1 2 26, 1 2 27, 1 2 28, 1 2 29, 1 2 30, 1 2 31, 1 2 32, 1 2 33, 1 2 34, 1 2 35, 1 2 36, 1 2 37, 1 2 38, 1 2 39, 1 2 40, 1 2 41, 1 2 42, 1 2 43, 1 2 44, 1 2 45, 1 2 46, 1 2 47, 1 2 48, 1 2 49, 1 2 50, 1 2 51, 1 2 52, 1 2 53, 1 2 54, 1 2 55, 1 2 56, 1 2 57, 1 2 58, 1 2 59, 1 2 60, 1 2 61, 1 2 62, 1 2 63, 1 2 64, 1 2 65, 1 2 66, 1 2 67, character limit attained

Comment: @thinkcool Though perhaps you want B=9 if you are concerned only with 3 digit numbers.